# Assistance with missing required positional arguments

Tags: python

```
def computeValue(condition , gps , wifi , camera):
    int(val1=0)
    int(val2=0)

    val1 = (condition + gps + wifi + camera)
    val2 = (condition + gps + wifi + camera)
    return val1
    return val2

def main():

    w=0;
    x=0;
    y=0;
    z=0;
    q=0;
    r=0;
    s=0;
    t=0;
# it then has conditions to assign values to wxyzqrst, and then

    val1 = computeValue(w+x+y+z)
    val2 = computeValue(q+r+s+t)
main()
```

> error: TypeError: computeValue() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'gps', 'wifi', and 'camera'

Anyone have any idea as to what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try passing 4 arguments?

Comment: 4 arguments? Where? Im sorry, complete noob at this

Comment: `w+x+y+z` is one argument. You need 3 more.

Comment: Have you been through the tutorial in the documentation?  Or any other type of learning aid?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, w+x+y+z is one, q+r+s+t is another, and those are the only ones that the program calls for, they're the only ones I need to add after obtaining them from the User. What other 2 could I use?

Comment: @wwii Ive gone through my textbooks section on it, cant find anything

Comment: No, they're each one, since they're separate calls.

Comment: Btw, gps wifi and camera all have boolean values when input by the user. Is that why there could be an error?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-AbramsI dont understand what you mean when you say that

Comment: You have defined a function that takes arguments - how many arguments are required?.  did you write ```computeValue```?   The call signature is ```computeValue(condition , gps , wifi , camera)``` - how many arguments does it take?

Comment: I did not write the computeValue statement/function, it was part of a given skeleton. The required arguments are 4: condition, gps, wifi and camera

Comment: You need to pass each argument separated by a comma.

Comment: But I need to add the values that I assign to the parameters

Comment: I got it! yes I understood now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Yu;

wwii, is right - a tutorial would do you great service as this is pretty foundational to programming so you are going to have a long road to travel if you don't take some time and learn the fundamentals.

However, in general, think of a function (computeValue in your case), as a mathematical algorithm. Imagine instead it was to compute the area of a rectangle. You would say Area = F(x,y) = x * y. From this you could say F(1,2)=2, F(2,2) = 4, F(4,3)= 12, and so on. But you couldn't say F(3*4) - that wouldn't make sense as it would mean the same as F(12). Your algorithm definition requires two arguments, not one.

Now - extend that to your computeValue function. You define it as requiring 4 arguments (aka parameters). However, you are trying to call it using "w+x+y+z". Python is going to be smart enough to add those values before calling the function. Much like F(12) above, you are only giving a single argument (or parameter). You need for values separated by a comma, such as computeValue(w,x,y,z)

Thats problem #1. Your next problem is that you can't return twice from a function (val1 and val2). You can return a list, array, tuple, etc. from a function and use each part but I think that will complicate things beyond what you are ready for at this point. For now, if you want two different calculations, just make two functions.